# TalendOpenStuido DI Replace content of one column of .slx File with another column of .csv file

Tags: talend

I have two input files:

1. an .xlsx file that looks like this:

[image]

1. an .csv files that looks like this:

[image]

I already have a talend job that transforms the .xlsx file into an .xml file.
One node in the .xml file contains the 
`<stockLocationCode>SL213</stockLocationCode>`

The output .xml file looks like this:
[image]

Now I need to replace every occurence of the stockLocationCode with the second column of the .csv file. In this case the result would be:
[image]

My talend job looks like this:

[image]

I use a `tMap` component to put the columns of the .xlsx file into the right node of the output xml file.

But I do not know how I can peplace the `StockLocactionCode` with the acutal full stock location using the .csv file. I tired to also map the .csv file with the `tMap` component.

I would neet to build in a methof that looks at the current value of the node `<stockLocationCode>` and loops over the whole .csv file until it find it in the first column of the .csv file and then replace the `<stockLocationCode>` content with the content of the second column of the .csv file.

Performance is not important ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, you'll need a lookup in e.g. a `tMap` or `tXMLMap` component, where you map your keys and add a new column with the second column of the csv file
- The resulting columns would look like this:

`Product; Stock Location Code; CSV 2nd column data`

- Now in a second map you could just remove the stock location code and do the rest of your job.

Voila, you exchanged the columns.

Answer (score 0):

u can use tXMLMap which lookup